# Google drive OAuth2: encrypted use of TokenResponse file?

Tags: encryption, google-drive-api, google-oauth, bearer-token

Is there possibility for encrypted use of the Google drive OAuth2 TokenResponse file?

My target:
If my token file is encrypted, end user can't use it (which is after the authority in browser) for another target.

Thanks in advance!

VB.NET code:

```
'prerequisites: create oauth2 client ids for gmail user and download file client_secret.json
Dim GooSvc As Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService
Dim UserInfo As Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential
Dim Stream1 = New System.IO.MemoryStream(New System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("content_of_client_secret.json"))
UserInfo = Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleClientSecrets.Load(Stream1).Secrets,
    New String() {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"},
    "user1",
    System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
    New Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore("d:\temp", True)).Result
GooSvc = New Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(New Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = UserInfo})
```

After this, the token file `d:\temp\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user1`:
- created automatically (after the authority in browser) if it's not exists
- refreshed automatically if it's out of date (after 1 hour)
- nothing happens with it, if it's "fresh" (within 1 hour)

Example content of the token file:

```
{"access_token":"ya29.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","Issued":"2019-06-02T13:21:54.775+02:00","IssuedUtc":"2019-06-02T11:21:54.775Z"}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I created two simple questions from the original double one (this remained the first, and id of the second is: 56428018), and I also simplified the details after the code.